# Angular: Insert new array of FormGroup inside FormArray

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Below is my code.

```
getAccountAssociatedDetails(account, index) {
        if (!!account) {
            this.agreementDetailsService.getDetails(account)
                .subscribe((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    const rows = <FormArray>this.manualDetailsForm.get('rows');
                    let associatedDetailsArray = <Array<any>>response.associatedDetails;
                    let newItems = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < associatedDetailsArray.length; i++)
                        newItems.push(this.buildDetail(associatedDetailsArray[i].account, associatedDetailsArray[i].huid, associatedDetailsArray[i].huidName, associatedDetailsArray[i].huidCountry));
                    rows.splice(index, 0, ...newItems);
                });
        }
    }
```

How to insert new array at a specific position of `FormArray`.

I'm getting error property `splice` does not exist on type `FormArray`. Please help me some other way to do this.

Comment: Thanks! Changed it to `for (let i = 0; i < associatedDetailsArray.length; i++)
      rows.insert(index, this.buildTPIItem(associatedDetailsArray[i].account, associatedDetailsArray[i].huid, associatedDetailsArray[i].huidName, associatedDetailsArray[i].huidCountry));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `insert` method

```
rows.insert(index, yourControl)
```

- https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#insert